# pycord: slash-command are dublicated while i run my bot

Tags: python, pycord

I've been searching and trying to fix it for hours and still didn't find the solution. If i run my bot sometimes it happens that the slash commands which i inplmented to the bot are doubled.
Sometimes the problem just fixes itself but up to now it's still doubled what i don't understand at all.
Does anyone already had experience with this problem and know how to fix it?

There's an image of the problem.

Thanks in advance for a reply.

[Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbTBQ.png)

Comment: Can you maybe show the part of the code where you add these commands?